# Front porch Ceiling Leak

Tags: leak, porch

[image]My front porch has what looks like an overflow pipe on the ceiling that is draining water drop by drop onto the front porch causing mold on the ground and puddles. Any ideas what the cause is?

Comment: Odd.  I can't think of a reason for that to be there.  Any chance there is an AC unit above?

Comment: You thought of the most likely reason after all, @crip659

Comment: @Ecnerwal   I was thinking of good reasons, not bad.

Comment: @crip659 No AC unit above. AC is located in the back yard.

Comment: What about an A/C duct?

Comment: Very few AC units are located entirely in the back yard. Usually half the AC unit is in the back yard and half the AC unit (which is the part that drips) is inside the house. Not infrequently in the attic.